# How does 200 million function call of fgets translate into only 25,224 system calls?

Tags: files, io

A I/O efficiency test from *APUE*:

Test file is said to be "98.5 MB with 3 million lines."

[image]

Code used in "Figure 3.6":

```c
#include "apue.h"

#define BUFFSIZE    4096

int
main(void)
{
    int     n;
    char    buf[BUFFSIZE];

    while ((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFSIZE)) > 0)
        if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n) != n)
            err_sys("write error");

    if (n < 0)
        err_sys("read error");

    exit(0);
}
```

*best time from Figure 3.6*: Use different `BUFFSIZE` and choose the best time

*single byte time from Figure 3.6*: Use `BUFFSIZE=1`

`err_sys` is merely a wrapper function for error handling.

`apue.h` is a also wrapper header file.

---

Code uses `fgets`:

```c
#include "apue.h"
int
main(void)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF){
        if (fputc(c, stdout) == EOF)
            err_sys("output error");
    }
        if (ferror(stdin))
            err_sys("input error");
    exit(0);
}
```

---

The question comes from:

> The last point of interest with these timing numbers is that the `fgetc` version is so much faster than the `BUFFSIZE=1` version from Figure 3.6. Both involve the same number of function calls—about 200 million—yet the `fgetc` version is more than 16 times faster in terms of user CPU time and almost 39 times faster in terms of clock time.
>   The difference is that the version using read executes 200 million function calls, which in turn execute 200 million system calls. With the `fgetc` version, we still execute 200 million function calls, but this translates into only **25,224** system calls. System calls are
>   usually much more expensive than ordinary function calls.

The test file is 98.5 MB ≈ 100 M, so 100 million calls for each I/O function call == 200 million calls, no problem here.

But how does 200 million `fgets` translate into **25,224** system call?

> With the `fgetc` version, we still execute 200 million function calls, but this translates into only **25,224** system calls.

How is *25,224* calculated?

Comment: Presumably `fgetc` and `fputc` do internal buffering of ~4k, dividing the whole count by 8k (98.5*1024*1024/4096 = 25216, which is remarkably close to the given number).

Comment: If so, I think internal buffering should be ~8K. Read function call == write function call = 25224 / 2 = 12612. 98.5*1024*1024/12612 = 8189 B. ~8K data transmitted for each read or write operation. Am I right here?

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot to double the 98.5 before.

Comment: You can set the stdio buffer size to whatever you want with `setvbuf()` (eg. to 1G), and then calculate yet another value ;-)

Comment: @mosvy Oh, that seems to be true. But by default do `fgetc` and `fputc` have some kind of buffer? I mean, they are I/O functions for char(single byte), may not need buffer I think. I can't find any source to prove which is right or wrong. :)

Comment: at the contrary, it's functions like fgetc or fputc (which may even be inlined) which need buffering the most, as the example from that book triea to demonstrate. In any case, they use full buffering by default (when not reading from some interactive device) in any implementation I may think of.